# "All things being equal" auf deutsch

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Was ist eine gute (d. h. für geschriebenes Deutsch) Übersetzung des englischen

```
All things being equal...
```

Comment: Alle Dinge, also auch Sätze, gleichen sich zwar, aber es ist auch hier notwendig, uns einen Kontext >> ... anzubieten, denn nur so kann man "gut" übersetzen.

Answer (score 2):

Das Idiom kann man auf unterschiedliche Weise übersetzen, zumal – so wie ich es verstehe – es einen kleinen aber feinen Unterschied zwischen *All things being equal* und *Other things being equal* gibt.

*(All) Other things being equal* bedeutet ja so viel wie "wenn zwei Dinge sich nur in dem gegebenen Punkt unterscheiden, dann ist X wahr oder trifft X ein".

*All things being equal* folglich bedeutet so viel wie "wenn sich die Bedingungen nicht ändern, dann ist X wahr oder trifft X ein".

Nehmen wir mal ein Beispiel:

> All things being equal, we should finish the job tomorrow.

Mögliche Übersetzungen hier sind:

- Wenn alles gleich bleibt
- Wenn nichts dazwischenkommt

Ein anderes Beispiel:

> And all things being equal, would you prefer that Michigan and Florida vote again?

Hier ist eine prägnante Übersetzung:

- Bei (sonst) gleichen Bedingungen
- Unter den gleichen Voraussetzungen

Es kommt also ganz auf den Kontext an. Und es kann auch im Englischen durchaus Sinn ergeben, *all* durch *other* zu ersetzen oder vice versa.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_things_being_equal vs http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/other_things_being_equal

Comment: @Vogel612 Kannst du mir einen Hinweis geben, worauf du hinaus willst? Wiktionary mag keinen Eintrag haben... Aber was ist dein Standpunkt?

Comment: ich meine, dass der von dir benannte "feststehende ausdruck" _other things being equal_ nicht in den gängigen "wörterbüchern" für idiome und redewendungen aufgelistet ist, weiterhin verweist _all things being equal_ direkt auf das von dir so kritisierte _ceteris paribus_, womit deine Übersetzungen für "All things being equal" leider nicht korrekt sind

Comment: @Vogel612 Naja, ich hab einen festen Satz an monolingualen Wörterbüchern und Corpora, die ich da zu rate ziehen. Und die kennen sehr wohl beide Formen, z.b. die [Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/equal?q=all+things+being+equal#equal__26). Und meine Übersetzungen basieren auf genau den Definition der monolingualen Dictionaries (auch wenn ich hier oft bilinguale Dictionaries zur Hilfe ziehe, um evnt. meine Wortwahl zu optimieren oder weitere Ideen zu erhalten).

Comment: @Vogel612 Bzgl. "c.p." ist meine Kritik ja nicht, dass es falsch ist, sonst hätte ich die andere Antwort ja downgevotet. Ich sage lediglich, dass es einfach zu wenige Menschen verstehen. Nämlich alle die, die nicht Latein in der Schule hatten und sich auch sonst keinen bildungssprachlichen Wortschatz angeeignet haben. Und ich bin kein Freund davon, Fremdworte zu verwenden, die nicht wirklich jeder kennt. Im Gegenteil sogar.

Answer (score 0):

Korrekt heißt es nicht "all things being equal", sondern "other things being equal". Eigentlich logisch, wenn man einen Moment darüber nachdenkt, oder?

Als gute Übersetzung biete ich an [**ceteris paribus**](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=%22ceteris+paribus%22&submit_button=Suche&view=1). Häufiger, wenn auch strenggenommen nicht dasselbe meinend, wird stattdessen [mutatis mutandis](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=mutatis+mutandis) verwendet.

Comment: *All things being equal* gibt es genauso. Und ob's logisch ist oder nicht steht auf einem anderen Blatt Papier. Immer kann es auch Hunde und Katzen regnen, dann ist's unerheblich ob alle Dinge oder doch nur andere Dinge sich gleichen. - Aber abgesehen davon, versteht der dt. Durchschnittsbürger diese Übersetzung nicht. Kein Wunder, ist ja auch kein Deutsch.

Comment: @em1 Nett, dass Sie mich über englische Sprache belehren wollen. Natürlich "gibt es" "all things being equal", Google zeigt 1,5 Mio. Hits dafür an. Es ist trotzdem falsch. Für "could care less" werden sogar 8.490.000 Hits angezeigt, das ändert nichts daran, dass es grundfalsch ist. Im übrigen ist "**all else being equal**" eher noch als "other things being equal" die Wendung der Wahl.

Comment: Dann solltest du mal monolinguale Dictionaries und Corpora belehren, dass sie da wohl was falsch übertragen haben. Es ist nicht alles falsch, was einem wie Murks vorkommt. Schade, eigentlich.

Comment: Im übrigen stehen Sie mit Ihrer Meinung, ceteris paribus sei kein Deutsch, ziemlich allein da. Beachten Sie die beiden Links zum Digitalen Wörterbuch der Deutschen Sprache. Denken Sie an Lingua franca, Status quo, Ombudsman, Hamburger, Portemonnaie, Trottoir: wenn Sie alle diese Fremdwörter wieder ausbürgern wollen, haben Sie ganz gut zu tun.

Comment: Goldwaage und so. Nochmal, nicht alles was im Duden steht, wird auch verstanden. Und ich verstehe es zum Beispiel nicht, hatte nämlich kein Latein in der Schule.

Comment: @Em1 Ich behaupte nicht, dass ceteris paribus _die_ amtliche, einzig gute Übersetzung ist. Aber man kann c.p. durchaus so in einen Satz einbauen, dass es auch denjenigen Lesern auf Anhieb verständlich ist, die es erstmals sehen. Allein die Beispiele aus der ZEIT auf DWDS zeigen, wie das geht. Es bleibt wie immer dem Fragesteller überlassen, ob er sich für diese oder eine andere Möglichkeit entscheidet, abhängig von Textsorte, Anlass, Kontext und eigenen Vorlieben.

Comment: man kann nicht einfach über "korrekt" bzw. "falsch" von feststehenden wendungen befinden! obwohl logisch natürlich korrekter kann man doch annehmen, dass ein impliziertes _other_ im laufe der Zeit mehr und mehr übergangen wurde. "all [other]" definiert eine komplett andere Menge als "other", wobei "all other" erstens klarer und zweitens logischer definiert ist

Comment: @Em1 Ich dachte, Wörter auf die Goldwaage zu legen sei der raison d'être von GLU? ;)

Comment: @Vogel612 Ich modifizierte ja bereits meine Aussage dahingehend, dass "all else being equal" und nicht "other things being equal" die Wendung der Wahl sein sollte. Das Recht, etwas als korrekt oder nicht zu bezeichnen, nehme ich mir einfach, mit Verlaub.